# Magento 2 saving category with incorrect store_id

Tags: magento2, category

After Migration of Magento 1.9 to Magento 2

Some categories have duplicated values (different store_id) on our database. (i dont know if this problem ocurred in Migration)

In a category:

Category Name: Battery

```
attribute_id=50
store_id=0
value="cms_block_1"
entity_id=3

attribute_id=50
store_id=1
value="cms_block_1"
entity_id=3
```

When saving this category on Admin (changing an attribute, ex), this value is change in just one store:

```
attribute_id=50
store_id=0
value="cms_block_2"
```

Context:

We have an separate docker container for Admin. Admin has in ip: (x.x.x.x) and Frontend (y.y.y.y) but they share the **same DATABASE.**

So in frontend, Magento get store_id=1 and in when editing a product on backend they get store_id=0.

How this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete all the rows which have **store # 0** in the table **catalog_category_entity_int, catalog_category_entity_varchar, catalog_category_entity_text, catalog_category_entity_decimal, catalog_category_entity_datetime**